# Hue accessing HDFS permission issues

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, hue

I have installed hadoop and some components from `http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_vd_cdh_package_tarball.html` following the cloudera path C installation guide.

If I access hdfs through the CLI i can create/put/delete etc without any problems

But in HUE filebrowser I can only read ... creating/uploading/deleting throws this error:

> Cannot access: //user/hue/test.txt. The HDFS REST service is not available. Hinweis: Sie sind ein Hue-Admin, aber kein HDFS-Superuser (das ist "admin").
>
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.2.60', port=50075): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/hue/test.txt?op=OPEN&doas=hdfs&user.name=hue&namenoderpcaddress=localhost:8020&length=3&offset=0 (Caused by : [Errno 61] Connection refused)

The german part above says: You are a Hue-Admin, but not a HDFS-Superuser (that is "admin")

I have started namenode/datanode/hue with the same user `admin`, I tried creating a new user in HUE called `admin` or even `hdfs` which didnt change anything.

Then I tried `dfs.permissions: false` but none of this works, I still get the same error as before and I have no idea why.

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: correction: I can see the folders etc in the filebrowser, but can not open/delete/upload etc any files (as shown in the example error above where I tried to open a test.txt file which i uploaded in the CLI) and I also tried to add the group `hue` with `dfs.permissions.supergroup: hdfs,hue` with no success

Comment: correction2: it seems like its only creating and opening files that causes this error. I can create and delete folders, I can also rename the test.txt file and even change its permissions but I can not open oder move it. Creating a new file in the filebrowser and uploading an existing file doesnt work either. This also causes problem when using PIG because I get the same error when I try to run a PIG script because it tries to save the script on HDFS. T

Comment: Are all you datanodes up, this is a typical error when the NaneNode is there (so you can create folders, modify medadata) but can't read any data?

Comment: Im running in pseudo-distributed so theres only one datanode, which is up and running. Exactly: opening for example a textfile, uploading a file or creating one doesnt work in the filebrowser, same goes for for any hue app that tries to save/create something on HDFS like the pig editor.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Hue is trying to access the datanode via my external IP (`192.168.x.x`) instead of `localhost(127.0.0.1)` even though I explicitly configured the `dfs.datanode.http.address` to be `localhost:50075`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Hue is just using the URL that the NN send him, you can try on the command line http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Open_and_Read_a_File you will see the same problem. You should check that the NN and DN share the same hdfs-site.xml with the correct property